# Print patterns of input string

Tags: c#, string

I want to use this string `"OMEGA"` to create and print its patterns.

Expected output:

```
MEGAO
EGAOM
GAOME
AOMEG
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and, if possible, [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: So you told us what you want. What did you try? We are not a code-writing service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just cycling through a string, you can easily use `Substring` or *C# 8* *Ranges* and then wrap it *Iterator Method*

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Enumerate(string value)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
      yield return value[i..] + value[0..i];
}
```

or

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Enumerate(string value)
   => value.Select((t, i) => value[i..] + value[0..i]);
```

or

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Enumerate(string value)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
      yield return value.Substring(i) + value.Substring(0,i);
}
```

**Usage**

```
foreach (var slice in Enumerate("OMEGA"))
    Console.WriteLine(slice);
```

**Output**

```
OMEGA
MEGAO
EGAOM
GAOME
AOMEG
```

*Note* :  If you don't want the original string, you can Just use `Skip`

```
foreach (var slice in Enumerate("OMEGA").Skip(1))
  ...
```

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Indices and ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes)
- [Iterators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators)